# Iterative SUMIF(?)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I have a dataset of multiple days. The number of records of each day are not the same. I want to sum the balance of each day ,but I want that the sum stops at the moment that the number of positive records of the day be greater than the number of negative records in 2!

The dataset (the colum `Obs` is not on the dataset, I just put to explain) is:

```
Day  Situation   Result    Obs
01    POSITIVE    +1     will be add 
01    POSITIVE    +2     will be add
01    POSITIVE    +3     Will not be add, because there is already 2 Positive and 0 negative on this day
01    NEGATIVE    -4     Will not be add ...
02    NEGATIVE    -1     Will be add
02    POSITIVE    +2     add
02    POSITIVE    +1     add
02    POSITIVE    +3     add
02    POSITIVE    +5     Will not be add, because there is already 3 Positive and 1 negative on this day
03    POSITIVE    +1     add
03    NEGATIVE    -1     add
03    NEGATIVE    -2     add
03    NEGATIVE    -3     add
03    NEGATIVE    -4     add
03    POSITIVE     5     add
03    POSITIVE     6     add
03    POSITIVE     7     add
03    POSITIVE     8     add
03    POSITIVE     9     add
03    POSITIVE     10    will not be add, because there is already 6 positive and 4 negative
```

The sum of each day is:
Day 01:+1+2=**+3**
Day 02:-1+2+1+3=**+5**
Day 03:`1-1-2-3-4+5+6+7+8+9=+26`

How can I do it with an EXCEL FORMULA?

Comment: based on your logic shouldn't the expected result be `Day 01 = 1+2 = 3` and `Day 02 = -1+2+1+3 = 5`? What if you have `1,-1,-2,-3,-4,5,6,7,8,9,10` for `Day 03`, what would be the expected result? I think you need to explain your logic further.

Comment: @TerryW you are correct. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a table to handle the dynamic structure of the data. 
Then I would add a column to this table called Should Count

I would add this formula to Should Count `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,"Positive",$A$2:$A2,A2)<=2`

It may look something like:
[image: Table of Data]

Finally, I would add a new table with a unique day number. In this case:

1
2
3

I would add this formula to the column next to the Days:`=SUMIFS(Table1[Result],Table1[Situation],"Positive",Table1[Day],G$2,Table1[Should Count],TRUE())`

this should give you a table that looks like:
[image: Results]

Comment: In that way, the count is stopping AFTER TWO POSITIVES, but that is not the objective. It has to stop when the number of positives be bigger than the number of negatives in two units, at that day. Tha records are sequentialy. For example, with yor data, at on day 3, just line 21 should not be counted. At line 20 there was 6 positive and 4 negative, so that should be tha last line counted.